# stack navigator return false when want to go to view

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigation

My application, having launched, initially opens the `HomeScreen` component.

My `App.js` file looks like this:

```
const App = createStackNavigator({
  HomeScreen: {
    screen: HomeScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'HomeScreen',
    },
    List: {
      screen: List,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: 'List',
      },
    },
  },
});
```

My `HomeScreen.js` file looks like this:

```
export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      Cars: [],
    };
    var d = new Database();
    d.initDB();
    let cars = [];
    d.listCar().then(data => {
      cars = data;
      this.setState({
        cars,
      });
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          backgroundColor: 'white',
          flexDirection: 'column',
        }}>
        <MyText text="Auta" />
        <Button
          title="Audi"
          onPress={() =>
            console.log(this.props.navigation.navigate('List')) //console log for debuging
          }
        />
        <Button
          title="Volkswagen"
          onPress={() =>
            this.props.navigation.navigate('List', {car_id: 1}) //want to pass props to List.js
          }
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

And my `List.js`:

```
const List = props => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{props.car_id}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```

When I click the button with the title prop `Audi` in my `HomeScreen` component, the `console.log` statement as part of the button callback returns: **false**.

When I click the buttons `Volskwagen` or `Audi` nothing happens.

I want to go from `HomeScreen` component to the `List` component and pass `car_id` from `HomeScreen` to `List` with props.

Why does the code above not redirect me from the `HomeScreen` component to the `List` component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you've put `List` into `HomeScreen` value, while React Navigation expects it to be declared on the same level as `HomeScreen`, like this:

```js
const App = createStackNavigator({
  HomeScreen: {
    screen: HomeScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'HomeScreen',
    },
  }
  List: {
    screen: List,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'List',
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: Amazing, it works! What about passing properties like `car_id`?

Comment: You can pass properties from one screen to another while navigating to it, by passing a second parameter to `navigate` function: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/navigation-prop/#navigate---link-to-other-screens

Comment: You can retrieve that value using `navigation.getParam('car_id')`.